# CI framework MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CI framework for the first time, and I need some help.

I am migrating an existing website over to the CI framework and have followed CI's tutorials step-by-step without much trouble, but there are a few roadblocks I can't seem to get past...

My database table has 2 columns - "country" and "city" - and I want to return a result in the view file that groups all rows by country, prints that country as a header, and then prints all corresponding cities as a list beneath the relevant country.

Ie.

```
<h1>England</h1>
<ul>
<li>Liverpool</li>
<li>London</li>
<li>Sheffield</li>
</ul>
```

Whereas before without CI framework, I could just write a query, return a result, redefine a variable and throw in a few if statements to achieve the desired result - the mvc structure of CI prevents me from doing so...

I gather the key to this mystery lies in the controller and creating some sort of array to manage the data and use in the view file - can somebody please help me with an example?

My existing controller is:

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Default_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->Default_model->getResults();
        $this->load->view('page_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Existing view file is:

```
<?php if (isset($query)):?>
<?php foreach ($query as $row):?>
<h1><?=$row->country?></h1>
<ul>
<li><?=$row->city?></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

And model:

```
function getResults()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY country, city ORDER BY country, city');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Can anybody help me with an example, just to show me how this type of query is handled within the CI mvc structure?

Currently, the returned result of the above code is:

```
<h1>England</h1>
<ul>
<li>Liverpool</li>
</ul>
<h1>England</h1>
<ul>
<li>London</li>
</ul>
<h1>England</h1>
<ul>
<li>Sheffield</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: please add the array dump of data of `$this->Default_model->getResults();` in your question

Comment: Do you mean what the results are of what this query returns? @dianuj

Comment: Your logic/code seems fine to me, what if any error are you reciving? instead of `return $query->result();` try doing a `var_dump($query->result());die();` and see if your actually getting any results ?

Comment: @user2505513 yes the results

Comment: @dianuj see above, post edited to include current query results.

Comment: I'm fairly certain grouping by "city" and "country" returns two different sets of the same rows. I can't test at the moment so this is just a comment rather than an answer but it's a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
<?php 
$country =$query[0]->country;
$index=1;
if (isset($query)):?>
<?php foreach ($query as $row):?>

<?php if($country==$row->country){ 

if($index==1){ ?> 
<h1><?=$row->country?></h1>
  <?php }
  $index++;
 }else{  
  $country=$row->country; 
 $index++;
 ?>
 <h1><?=$row->country?></h1>
<?php } ?>

<ul>
<li><?=$row->city?></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I had considered using a $i variable loop, but would this not compromise the mvc structure with too much php in view file? @dianuj

Comment: First of all your results array is wrong you have to make an array like a single country should have the an array of its cities then other country with its cities like parent array then its sub array

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean - but I want to be sure... Do you mean my query should return the country only, then run a second query within the loop that returns the cities equal to the current country? I was once advised to not run a query loop within a query loop... Is this correct? @dianuj

Comment: yes that what i m trying to say but if you do not run the query in the loop then you have to play like this in php

Comment: It won't work lad. I can't define the country in the second query in the model. It just produces an error about undefined variable... So it would appear as though I DO need to play about with php like this. I believe the key to this is in the controller and creating some sort of array to return the desired results from the query in the model. Does anybody have ANY guidance? @dianuj