# Codeigniter group by array

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, group-by

HELP!

I am trying to generate a "past events" page for my CI website, using a MySQL database table called "events". There are 100+ rows of data, some duplicate, that range across 5 major countries - England, Ireland, Norther Ireland, Scotland and Wales - many different major  cities - again, including duplicate entries - and venues.

I have struggled for a couple of weeks now with how to query and return the data in the following format:

```
<h1>** grouped country **</h1>
<h2> ** grouped city **</h2>
<p>** grouped venue **</p>
```

Such as:

```
<h1>England</h1>
<h2>London</h2>
<p>Tower of London</p>
<h2>Manchester</h2>
<p>Canal Street</p>
<p>Old Trafford</p>
<h1>Ireland</h1>
<h2>Dublin</h2>
<p>St. James' Gate</p>
<h1>Scotland</h1>
<h2>Glasgow</h2>
<p>Buchanan Street</p>
<p>Tron Theatre</p>
```

I am DELIBERATELY not including any of my code for model, view and controller, as what I have thus far seems to confuse people as to what I'm trying to achieve when they see it. And I'm open to the fact I may be attacking this from the wrong angle altogether... I just need to result the above!

It feels as if this SHOULD be a fairly simple thing to achieve, but I NEED HELP!

Comment: Is this not simply a case of ordering your data set by country, city, venue and then looping through the result?

Comment: Sort of. BUT it will then repeat country, city and venue on EVERY loop, as opposed to stacking the corresponding information beneath the parent grouped variable

Comment: That's precisely what the loop is for - while something is x do one thing, when it changes do the other thing!

Comment: Is it a straight-forward case of a single query and getting above result by manipulating the view, or do I break down each element (query for country, query for city, query for venue etc.) and then loop the results inside one another? @Strawberry :)

Comment: See below - although Flashin got there first...

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the result by country, city and then venue.

When you loop, you can do the following

```
<?php
$lastCountry = null;
$lastCity = null;
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT country, city, venue FROM venues ORDER BY country, city, venue"); // CI query
foreach($list = $query->result_array()) {
    if($list['country'] != $lastCountry) {
        $lastCountry = $list['country'];
        print "<h1>".$list['country']."</h1>";
    }
    if($list['city'] != $lastCity) {
        $lastCity = $list['city'];
        print "<h2>".$list['city']."</h2>";
    }
    print "<p>".$list['venue']."</p>";
}
```

Comment: Does the above answer not compromise the integrity of a view file however?

Comment: What do you mean with compromising the integrity?
How you output this is up to you.. You can put the loop in the view too, and put the query in the model where it's supposed to be.

Comment: I understand that, however - is the view file not supposed to be as free of php as possible? The if files, fair enough - but defining variables etc. is the view file not the incorrect place for this? @Flashin ps. This is really helpful, thank you.

Comment: @user2505513 this what i suggested you in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391764/ci-framework-mysql-query/17399813#comment25267009_17399813

Comment: It is, and thank you @dianuj but I just got to the point where I needed someone to show me an example. I'm still a bit unsure as to whether defining $lastCountry and $lastCity variables in view file is "correct" though. Does anyone know?

Comment: IMHO it is not bad because you only are using those variables to build the view, not for anything else. 
If you don't like that you can always define those in the controller and do it like that!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Flashin's answer (and ignoring my use of deprecated methods), the procedural solution could look something like this...

```
$query = "
SELECT
     *
  FROM venues
 ORDER
    BY country
     , city
     , venue;
";

$lastCountry = null;
$lastCity = null;
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['country'] != $lastCountry) {
        $lastCountry = $row['country'];
        print "<h1>".$row['country']."</h1>";
    }
    if($row['city'] != $lastCity) {
        $lastCity = $row['city'];
        print "<h2>".$row['city']."</h2>";
    }
    print "<p>".$row['venue']."</p>";
}
```